# convert a Workbook to a Resource

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

I want to convert a `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook` to a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`. Currently, I do this like so

```
public Resource toResource(Workbook workbook) {
  var outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  workbook.write(outputStream);
  return new ByteArrayResource(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

It seems like there ought to be a more straightforward way, that doesn't require the intermediate `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Can this code be simplified?

Comment: Why do you need a resource?

Comment: @M.Deinum because I need to call a 3rd party API that only accepts a Resource

Comment: Where is this `Workbook` coming from? If it is a file on the system don't read the workbook but rather pass the file, else this would be more or less the only way (apart from storing it as a file).

Comment: @M.Deinum it's not a file on the system, it's created (in memory) using Apache POI

Comment: Then this is the only way around that, which might eventually lead to problems as you have everything in memory. With large workbooks this might lead to out-of-memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

`Workbook.write()` requires a parameter of type `OutputStream`, so there is no way around using that `ByteArrayOutputStream`.